# What's the best website for learning HTML Semantically?

Tags: html, css, semantics

Where should I point someone to learn the basics of HTML/CSS? I personally got my start from [HTMLGoodies](http://htmlgoodies.com/) way back in the day, but while I thank Ken Burns for getting me going, I'm loathed to send someone out to that site nowadays as I think it's dated.

Obviously there are many sites out there that cumulatively contain all the information needed, but where to send someone new who you don't want to scare off?

---

edit:

I honestly thought I'd been missing something by not having used [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com/), but I see that within three pages of the tutorial (both html and xhtml) they use `<b></b>`. Damned shame they're not encouraging semantics.

Anyone know something that gets people off on the right foot?

Comment: > they use <b></b>
this really simplify learning html by this. If they user some id,classes and reference to css stylesheets from the very beginning  this can cause difficulties in understanding of base concepts of html.

Comment: @koldfyre - bold implies aesthetics rather than content. strong implies that this should be read with conviction. same goes for em (emphasis) and the italics tag.  Think about how a screen reader should read italics or bold, and you'll see why they're a no-no.

Comment: @sergdev - I agree that they shouldn't be introducing styles, but they shouldn't be encouraging bold as an element when it's one of the most miss used elements in the book. Bold is a presentational element and semantics/standards drives us to separate content and presentation for good reason.

Comment: I'm annoyed with systems that translate <i> to <em>, though. <i> is semantic: it's used for many grammatical constructions, such as ship names, book titles, and the discussion of words as words: Compare "Socrates was a Greek philosopher" with "<i>Socrates</i> has eight letters". I'm not so sure whether bold tags are semantically accurate.

Comment: @timothy.green.name - I agree that there are valid reasons for the italics element and I like that you've pointed it out. I just wish that tutorial sites would introduce it at a later, more advanced, stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly, I personally started off on HTMLGoodies, also. I think tizag.com is more updated.

Comment: I'm just a few pages in and can clearly see that this is the one I was looking for. Simple, friendly, and just like HTMLGoodies but without the clutter they introduced over the years. Still the dreaded bold tag though

Comment: I recommend you to check this more up-to-date site http://www.snoopcode.com much better than w3schools and tizag

Answer (score 21):

I can't believe how many people are answering with w3schools.  I couldn't recommend enough that people never EVER mention this place again.  It is a terrible resource.

A few good places:

**Addition for HTML5:** http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/

http://alistapart.com

http://www.quirksmode.org/

http://www.thinkvitamin.com/

Not complete, but alistapart.com is required reading for any web developer we hire.

Comment: @Mike - I fully agree with the list as further reading, but I'm explicitly looking for places to send a complete newbee who I don't want to feel intimidated. HTML is easy, but you need to get over that first hump.

Comment: And +1 for whatever books Jeffrey Zeldman writes.

Comment: I love A List Apart. We've just hired a new designer for artwork/logos and stuff. He's done a fair bit of flash, but he's never worked for the web before. I pointed him to A List Apart.

Comment: Why are you so down on W3Schools? They are actually pretty good to get the basics. If you are completely new to HTML et al. then I fully recommend W3Schools for HTML and CSS. If you want more than that, I recommend google searching how people have solved your problem. So I stress getting basics from W3, then google specific things when you need it. To each his own I guess.

Answer (score 8):

Also, never underestimate the power of reading the source on well-written websites.

Comment: Didn't deserve a negative rep for that. Reading other people's markup would be my homework assignment.

Comment: Some people learn best by looking at something that works, take it apart and then put it back together remixed.  However, not everybody learns that way, just keep it in mind.

Answer (score 4):

I can't believe that people here are recommending W3Schools. That's the last place I would recommend anyone to go.

The one place I would recommend the user heading to is SitePoint. A lot of the articles there are aimed at advanced users, although the sheer quality of the forum and the beginner articles are too good to pass. I would also agree with [Mike's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375763/whats-the-best-website-for-learning-html-semantically#375898) recommendations as places to send a complete novice.

As far as getting the practical skill, the one thing I would recommend is opening up a text editor or a good IDE in text-editor mode and just writing a website to see what happens. Head to the [Open Source Web Design](http://www.oswd.org/) page and see how others have created basic layouts, then apply that skill to your own.

Answer (score 4):

[HtmlDog](http://www.htmldog.com/) has a good set of guides for beginners, intermediate and advanced users.  It also has useful references for all things HTML & CSS.

Comment: looks good, starts on the right foot

Answer (score 4):

I really like [yourHTMLsource](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/). Quirksmode and AlistApart are great. And [Ajaxian](http://ajaxian.com/) is more advanced and wide resource of things.
I began on w3schools, however soon this site became the one I avoid the most.

Answer (score 3):

[Read this book](http://www.zeldman.com/dwws/) (Designing with Web Standards by Zeldman)

Comment: I find Zeldman to be more for people already in the game, although you shouldn't be in the game without having read it.

Answer (score 3):

To keep this answers to this question up-to-date, the [Opera Web Curriculum](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/1-introduction-to-the-web-standards-cur/) is, as of 2011, the best way to learn front-end web development. It is comprehensive, encourages best practice, and is generally a superior resource for those completely new to the field.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should check [www.tutorialrepublic.com](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com). This site has great tutorials on HTML/CSS. I learned HTML/CSS from this site and I really like this, they explains the topic very clearly.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't believe that people here are
>   recommending W3Schools. That's the
>   last place I would recommend anyone to
>   go.
>   For me its a great...
>   Maybe isn't "the" reference website, but is a very good and practical cheatsheat about html and stuff...

The htmldom section is one of the best for me...

Comment: If you want a reference then the best place is easily the specification itself. Once you get a feel for the structure and you've read and tested enough source code from other sites you're more than capable of writing your own.

Comment: @MikeB The spec itself is like reading a legal document. It is overly complicated to simply learn a few things. I only resort to the spec when I am not sure if my markup is valid.

Answer (score 1):

If you speak German, the best Site for learning HTML is:
http://selfhtml.org

Comment: Why not have a link? http://selfhtml.org.