# finding for a detailed tutorial for HTML

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What's the best website for learning HTML Semantically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375763/whats-the-best-website-for-learning-html-semantically)
>   [What are some good websites for learning HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068195/what-are-some-good-websites-for-learning-html)

i want to learn HTML from basics as i'm noob regarding this, i want a complete detail tutorial of this, i search it in w3school.com but didn't get any detailed information, i'm going to start a project regarding this, so please refer me a detailed and complete tutorial from basics.

Comment: to me w3schools is a good tutorial. You will be give adequate information on each and every concept.. if you need further details you then go ahead and google for that tag.

Comment: Marked as duplicate. There are tons of Qs here on the same question.

Answer (score 2):

You can [buy a book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321687299) and follow these [samples](http://introducinghtml5.com/)

Answer (score 1):

First off, look at the `Related` section on the right-bottom side of this page

A few more links

https://developer.mozilla.org/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML

http://net.tutsplus.com/

http://blogs.sitepoint.com/

Comment: I recommend you to add this new website called SnoopCode. This is way better than w3schools or anything out there. http://www.snoopcode.com

Answer (score 1):

http://www.html.net/tutorials/html/ seems quite a good starting point for beginners.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

try this [Basic HTML Tutorial](http://www.pageresource.com/html/index2.htm)

and this is the best [Ken Ward's Html Tutorial](http://www.sanfords.net/Framed_pages/KenWardsHTMLTutorial.htm)